# Connection refused when accessing Node.js API from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, api, https, passport.js

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to implement user authentication in my Angular web page. As a backend I use Node.js Express framework and for authentication I use passport.

When I access sever URL from browser, it works normally, but when I call API from Angular with the same URL, I got connection refused error 404.

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (users, line 0)

This is my URL that works in browser, but not in Angular(I use https):
    https://192.168.1.103:8000/users

This is how my Angular API looks:

```
get_user() {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'users', {
      observe: 'body',
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    });
  }
```

My API on the Node server looks like:

```
router.get('/users', isValidUser, function (req, res, next) {
  return res.status(200).json(req.user)
});

function isValidUser (req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) next ();
  else
    return res.status(401).json({message: 'Unauthorized request'});

}
```

Output from browser console looks like this:

```
[Error] ERROR
HttpErrorResponse

error: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/stylesheets/style.css\"></head><body><h1>No…"

headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function}

message: "Http failure response for https://192.168.1.103:8000/users: 404 Not Found"

name: "HttpErrorResponse"

ok: false

status: 404

statusText: "Not Found"

url: "https://192.168.1.103:8000/users"

Prototyp HttpErrorResponse
    defaultErrorLogger (vendor.js:43427)
    handleError (vendor.js:43479)
    next (vendor.js:74051)
    (anonymná funkcia) (vendor.js:69627)
    __tryOrUnsub (vendor.js:115680)
    next (vendor.js:115619)
    _next (vendor.js:115567)
    next (vendor.js:115544)
    next (vendor.js:115330)
    emit (vendor.js:69589)
    run (polyfills.js:3359)
    onHandleError (vendor.js:73335)
    runTask (polyfills.js:3406)
    invokeTask (polyfills.js:3700)
    timer (polyfills.js:5885)
```

Comment: What is saved in `environment.apiUrl` ?

Comment: That is my IP address from file enviroment.ts

Comment: Could you console and paste it here the output

Comment: I updated question, you can find it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a post request instead of a get request in your angular code. I assume you have no post route for `/users` defined in nodejs, hence the error

Try

```
get_user() {
return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'users', {
  observe: 'body',
  withCredentials: true
});
```

}

Also you do not need to set the Content-Type header as it's automatically set by angular HttpClient